# Unityのエラーについて

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d

unityエラーの解決方法を教えてください。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
GameView.Repaint Waiting for Unity’s code in UnityEditer.CoreModule.dll to finish executing.
```

数日前から何度も同じエラーが出ています。
強制終了などで再度やり直したり、10分以上放置していると消えて、しばらくは使用できるのですが、少し経つとまたエラー吐きます。

#### エラーについて：

エラーメッセージ殆どはGameView.Repaint Waiting for Unity’s code in UnityEditer.CoreModule.dll to finish executingたまにscene hierarchy Window rdpaint　Waiting for Unity’s code in UnityEditer.CoreModule.dll to finish executing
マウスポインターが↔になる。（動くがクリックなど反応なし）

#### 発生時の状況、エラータイミング、頻度：

（※Unity：2021.3.1時） Unityにてパーティクルシステムでエフェクト作成の作業時に出現、決まった挙動の時に出ているわけではない。２日前ごろから、しばらく問題なく作業できるが作業開始後２時間後や再起動すぐになどに出現。その後10分ほどすると消えるが再度出現、それはすぐにだったり、しばらくしてからだったり不規則。
(※2022.1.23に更新後)再度同様のエラーが出現する。ただ５分以内に消えるときもある。

#### 今までしたこと：

強制終了、タスクマネージャーから削除、待つ、バージョン更新

##### UNITY環境：

2022.1.23f1 <プロジェクト：３D>

##### PC環境：

AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5650GE with Radeon Graphics 3.40 GHz、64.0 GB (63.4 GB 使用可能)、Windows11 Home、22H2、390Mbps

##### もしかしたら：

バージョンアップして間もないのですが、エラーは出ています。その中で、シーンビューとゲームビューを横並べで制作しているのですが、ゲームビュー、シーンビューなどのウインドウ(?)、プロジェクト画面（?）の比率を変更しようとした時にエラーが出ます。

（上記から約２時間後）その後、やはりHierarchyやScene、Gameなどのウインドウの比率を調節しようとするとエラーが出ました。

Comment: 最初のオブジェクト？名が違うので関係の有無は不明ですが検索するとこんな記事が見つかります。使っている何かが最新になっていないとかかもしれませんので調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [Projectbrowser.repaint - waiting for UnityEditor.CoreModule.dll to finish executing](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1915587/projectbrowserrepaint-waiting-for-unityeditorcorem.html), [Stuck on ProjectBrowser.repaint infinitely when loading project.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/sjttim/stuck_on_projectbrowserrepaint_infinitely_when/)

Comment: ありがとうございます！先程、2021.3.11だったので、2022.1.23.f1*にしたのですが、また出ました。コメント嬉しいです。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 上記のエラー後、続けてscene hierarchy Window rdpaint Waiting for Unity’s code in UnityEditer.CoreModule.dll to finish executing.が表示されました。もう自分はUnityを扱うのは諦めろという事でしょうか。

Comment: どんな環境で何をしようとしてどのような問題が発生しているのか、他の人が再現・調査出来る程度に詳しい情報やソースコードを記述してみてください。その過程で自分で解決できることがあるかもしれません。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: kunif様　誠にありがとうございます!そしてきちんとお伺い出来てない失礼な状態にも関わらずあがとうございました。

Comment: Unity そのもののバグだと思いますけど、開発用ウインドウのレイアウト関係のバグは数年前から根強く残ってしまっています。
Window > Layouts > Default とか Window > Layouts > Reset All Layouts をするとしばらくエラーが出なくなることが多いので、Unity を再起動する前にこれらを試してみる価値はあると思います。